# compare 2 values between 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, compare

My code looks like:

```
foreach($client->GetSMSMessages($params)->GetReceivedMessages->ReceivedMessage as $value){

   foreach($get_customer as $customer){

      if(substr($customer['mobile'],1) == $value->MobileNumber || $customer['mobile'] == $value->MobileNumber){

      $name = $customer['name'];

     }else{
     $name = '';
     }
  }
$json['received'][] = array (
//'rec_id' => $value->SMSID,
'rec_sms' => $value->Body,
'rec_customer' => $name, 
'rec_tel' =>  $value->MobileNumber,
'rec_date' => $value->DateTime
 );
 }
```

What i'm trying to achieve without success is to compare the variable `$customer['mobile']` to `$value->MobileNumber` and if there's any value matching to print the customers name (`$name = $customer['name']`).

Any ideas ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: You need to break out of the inner loop when you find a match. Otherwise, you'll just go on to the next customer, it won't match, and you'll set `$name = ''`.

Comment: Would it kill you to post nicely indented code? I think I spend more time fixing people's code indentation than I do posting actual answers.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for answering, but how to break out from the second loop?

Comment: With a `break` statement, of course!

Comment: @Barmar   Thanks a lot! Forgot about it :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the loop when you find a match, so you don't set `$name` back to `''` on the next iteration.

Actually, there's no need to set `$name = ''` every time. Just initialize it before the loop, and set it to the found customer name when you find a match.

```
foreach($client->GetSMSMessages($params)->GetReceivedMessages->ReceivedMessage as $val){
    $name = '';
    foreach($get_customer as $customer){
        if(substr($customer['mobile'],1) == $value->MobileNumber || $customer['mobile'] == $value->MobileNumber){
            $name = $customer['name'];
            break;
        }
    }
    $json['received'][] = array (
        //'rec_id' => $value->SMSID,
        'rec_sms' => $value->Body,
        'rec_customer' => $name, 
        'rec_tel' =>  $value->MobileNumber,
        'rec_date' => $value->DateTime
    );
}
```